# Multiple cell dropdown List

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I'd like to create a dropdown list that spans multiple columns, like so:

`Greek Yogurt | 20 | 17 | 2
Turkish Honey | 13 | 10 | 0`

So in another cell (in another Sheet) I can select from these two options as a range, and populate a row in Sheet1 with this data.

Basically what I'd like to do is have a Sheet with all foods and their macros, then be able to select a food from this dynamic list in Sheet 1. It's very time consuming to have to fill in each column over and over again. Instead, if I had a "database" of food items that could be selected, making a meal plan would be a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a table that looks like your example and name it `NamedRange1` for example then if your foods are in ColumnA starting in A1:

```
 =ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup($A1:$A,NamedRange1,column(),0),""))
```

in B1 and copied across to D1, then B1:D1 downwards, should suit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a special column in the range that is referenced by the Data Validation Criteria, that concatenates the values of multiple cells.

[Concatenate](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123)

That would put multiple values in the drop down menu item.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

1- create a spreadsheet called "database" (or whatever name you want) with the list of all the food you have and the columns with each info you want (calories, proteins, etc).

2- Open a new spreadsheet "meal plan". 
a)Add a tab called "database" which brings the info from the database. You can do this by using the importrange formula. IMPORTRANGE("database url"; interval). 
b)Add another tab called "meal plan" with a column called ingredient. Make this column a drop-down by adding data validation (go to: data, data validation, list, and use the database tab as the interval)
c)Beside the column ingredient add the columns you wish to autopopulate from the database. To autopopulate just use vlookup formula.

If you have trouble with any of this just tell me and I can help you build it.